# STRIPE ERROR: stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Request req_Z2KfeZdvlmvT: Missing required param: business_profile

Tags: python, django, stripe-payments, payment-gateway, stripe-customer-portal

In stripe it is mentioned that buisness_profile is required but the child parameters are option and I am still getting this error stripe.error.InvalidRequestError: Request req_Z2KfeZdvlmvT: Missing required param: business_profile. Here's the [link](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customer_portal/configurations/create#create_portal_configuration-business_profile).

```
response = stripe.billing_portal.Configuration.create(
    business_profile={
        'headline': None,
        'privacy_policy_url': None,
        'terms_of_service_url': None
    },
    features={
        'customer_update': {
            'allowed_updates': ['name', 'email', 'address', 'phone'],
            'enabled': True
        },
        'invoice_history': {
            'enabled': True
        },
        'payment_method_update': {
            'enabled': True
        },
        'subscription_cancel': {
            'cancellation_reason': {
                'enabled': True,
                'options': ['too_expensive', 'switched_service', 'unused', 'other']
            },
            'enabled': True,
            'mode': 'immediately',
            'proration_behavior': 'create_prorations'
        },
        'subscription_pause': {
            'enabled': False
        },
        'subscription_update': {
            'default_allowed_updates': [],
            'enabled': False,
            'proration_behavior': 'always_invoice'
        }
    },
    login_page={
        'enabled': True,
    }
)
```

what is the possible reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

Does the error go away if you set a value for one of the child parameters? I wonder if the API reference just lists it as optional but API doesn't like it when the values are set to `None`.

The other thing you can check is in your Stripe logs, does the incoming request body contain `business_profile` key? If not, then that could be the issue.